# Exclude remotes from git log --graph

Tags: git

I would like to show a simple graph of the relationships between all my git branches. So far the closest I have gotten is this command:

> git log --graph --oneline --branches --decorate --simplify-by-decoration

However, the project I work on has a *ton* of remote branches used by other developers that I don't care about and their inclusion in the graph make it hard to see the connections between my branches. I have tried adding `--not --remotes="*"`, but that eliminates so many commits that I completely loose the tree structure and just get a list like `branch -v`.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I would like to find the best solution possible using the standard command line tools, as I'm usually not working at my own computer, and can't depend on other third party software being installed.

Comment: Just delete the branches you don't care about from your repo.  Your repo is yours.  You can always get them back from upstream.  For an alternate way of achieving (almost) the same effect, you could clone your repo locally and work in the clone, none of the remotes will appear there.

Comment: @jthill That might be the way to go, although new branches are created fairly often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a crude but effective method:

```
temp=`mktemp -u`
git clone -s --bare `git rev-parse --git-dir` $temp
git --git-dir=$temp log --graph --decorate --oneline --branches --simplify-by-decoration
rm -rf $temp
```

The `-s` option tells git to make a ridiculously lightweight clone, and `git log` doesn't need a worktree.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a gui git tool like gitg (linux) / gitx (OSX) where you can pick local branches only as in:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I spend most of my time working in kiosks and labs where I don't have the ability to install new software. We have gitk, but it's filtering capabilities seem identical to the command line git tools.